# For loop with if else skipping last item Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to create a list with only the numbers of initial list. I created a code to retrieve the numbers but it skips the last item. I can´t figure out why it does it. Thanks :)

```
list1=['a13','b23','c33','d43']  #a13=item   a,1,3 = subitems
list2=[]
list3=[]
for item in list1:
    for subitem in item:
        if subitem.isdigit()==True:
            list2.append(subitem)
            if len(list2)<=2:
                join_digit=''.join(list2)
            else:
                list3.append(join_digit)
                list2=list2[-1:]
print(list3)
```

Output:

```
['13','23','33']
```

Expected output:

```
['13','23','33','43']
```

Comment: what is the logic of `join_digit` in the `else` scope,  the initial condition would fail and go to `else` since it's greater than 2 elements.  what happens if you `print(list2)` after checking the `isdigit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending to `list3` while processing the next item; the last item is processed, but never appended to `list3`.

Probably the whole logic with the `if`/`else` needs to be removed; instead, do things outside the inner `for` loop:

```
list1 = ['a13', 'b23', 'c33', 'd43']  #a13=item   a,1,3 = subitems
list3 = []
for item in list1:
    list2 = []
    for subitem in item:
        if subitem.isdigit():
            list2.append(subitem)
    joined_digits = ''.join(list2)
    list3.append(joined_digits)
print(list3)
```

(I'm also omitting the `== True`, which is superfluous here.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code else statement runs on next loop(which adds digit to list). so you need to add one more `list3.append` to add last word.

````
list1=['a13','b23','c33','d43']  #a13=item   a,1,3 = subitems
list2=[]
list3=[]
for item in list1:
    for subitem in item:
        if subitem.isdigit()==True:
            list2.append(subitem)
            if len(list2)<=2:
                join_digit=''.join(list2)
            else:
                list3.append(join_digit)
                list2=list2[-1:]
if join_digit !=list3[-1]:
   list3.append(join_digit)
print(list3)```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=['a13','b23','c33','d43']
answer=[]
for string in list1:
    sub=""
    for char in string:
        if char.isdigit():
            sub += char
    answer.append(sub)
print(answer)
```